# How to divide the logic between Redux reducers and action creators?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have some logic that I've put in the reducer which I'm thinking should be possibly put in the Action and passed down?

Is it best practice to put this sort of stuff in the actions or reducer?

Working example [here](https://jsbin.com/tumebimive/edit?html,js,console,output).

Reducer code:

```
function Card() {
  this.card = (Math.random()*4).toFixed(0);
}

Card.prototype = {
  getRandom: function(){
    var card;
    //console.log(this.card)
    switch (this.card) {
      case '1':
      card = 'heart';
      break;
      case '2':
      //card = 'diamonds';
      card = 'heart'; // weight the odds abit
      break;
      case '3':
      card = 'club';
      break;
      case '4':
      card = 'spade';
      break;
      default:
      card = 'heart';
      break;
    }
    return card;
  }
}

var dealer = {
  deal: function(){
    var results = [];
    for(var i = 0; i <4; i++){
      var card = new Card();
      results.push(card.getRandom());
    }
    console.log(results);
    return results;
  }
}


const initialState = {
  count: 0,
  data: []
}

function counter (state = initialState, action) {
  let count = state.count
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'increase':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        data: dealer.deal(),
        count: state.count+1
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: Reducers should contain the logic for mutating the state but it is best practice not to write this inside the switch statement but extract the logic to a seperate function passing the currentstate and returning the new  state.

A great tutorial: http://teropa.info/blog/2015/09/10/full-stack-redux-tutorial.html#loading-entries

Comment: "Reducers should contain the logic for mutating the state " ?

Comment: The reducer should contain all logic to mutate the given state. But it is best practice to extract this logic to seperate functions instead of writing it inline between case statements for example:
```return addUsers(currentState, action) -> newState```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Your reducer must be pure. Currently it is not pure. It calls `deal()` which calls `getRandom()` which relies on `Math.random()` and thus is not pure.

This kind of logic (“generating data”, whether randomized or from user input) should be in the action creator. Action creators don’t need to be pure, and can safely use `Math.random()`. This action creator would return an action, **an object describing the change**:

```
{
  type: 'DEAL_CARDS',
  cards: ['heart', 'club', 'heart', 'heart']
}
```

The reducer would just add (or replace?) this data inside the state.

In general, **start with an action object.** It should describe the change in such a way that running the reducer with the same action object and the same previous state should return the same next state. This is why reducer cannot contain `Math.random()` calls—they would break this condition, as they would be random every time. You wouldn't be able to test your reducer.

After you figure out how the action object looks (e.g. like above), you can write the action creator to generate it, and a reducer to transform state and action to the next state. **Logic to generate an action resides in action creator, logic to react to it resides in the reducer, reducer must be pure.**

Finally, **don’t use classes inside the state**. They are not serializable as is. You don’t need a `Card` class. Just use plain objects and arrays.

Comment: What's the logic behind generating actions in the action creators? What if that logic is stored in the reducer? (I'm assuming that logic is pure) What's wrong with that? I had a look at the redux + elm documentation and couldn't find any reference to it. Would you mind elaborate/pointing me to the right doc?

Comment: @danielepolencic I’m afraid this is a vague question. If you offer a specific example I will be happy to discuss it.

Comment: @danielepolencic if the logic is in the action creator, then replaying the created actions will always yield the same state.  If the logic is in the reducer then the results of replaying the actions aren't guaranteed to be the same.  

That may not matter in some cases, but it's required if you want the redux dev tools to work well.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that actions should be simple objects that contain two things: (i) the action type and (ii) what changed (i.e. the new data).

Reducers on the other hand, are pure functions that take actions and the previous app state as inputs and return the new app state.  How they accomplish this is up to you.  You can add whatever logic necessary to take the combination of previous state + action and return the new state *as long as you don't mutate data outside your reducer function(s).*

As for your code specifically, I'm not sure the `deal()` function belongs in either an action or a reducer.  I think a better place might be in some sort of event handler (e.g. `onClick`). You could then pass the *results* of the deal call as an action to your reducer.

Comment: sorry just to elaborate: i didn't mean inside the action, i meant with the action code (in the module). I'm starting to think possible in some sort of utils module?

Comment: Yeah I like to keep my actions modules pretty simple.  Basically just a bunch of functions that return the type and new data.  How that new data gets derived comes from elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It appears then it's a best practice to have an static class that handles the first level entery points that instantiates the redux actions outside of the  redux.

I suppose that makes sense to keep the store and action chains pure.

This might look like a lot of replicated code at first but when you start dispatching based on conditions or need to dispatch from multiple places it starts to open up and make sense.