# Where to store WebRTC streams when building React app with redux

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webrtc, redux

I'm building a React.js application that interacts with the WebRTC apis to do audio/video calling. When a call is successfully established, an 'onaddstream' event is fired on the RTCPeerConnection instance, which contains the stream that I as a developer am supposed to connect to a video element to display the remote video to the user.

Problem I'm having is understanding the best way to get the stream from the event to the React component for rendering. I have it successfully working by just dumping the stream into my redux state, but [in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098125/how-to-divide-the-logic-between-redux-reducers-and-action-creators/34135166#34135166), the creator of redux Dan Abramov mentioned this:

> [...] don’t use classes inside the state. They are not serializable as is. [...] Just use plain objects and arrays.

Which leaves me wondering, if I shouldn't put these streams in the redux state, is there a better way to react to the 'onaddstream' event and get the React component to update without putting the stream in the redux state?

Comment: Similarly - where in the app structure do you put non-serializable state objects, like instances of `RTCPeerConnection` or `MediaStream`, if not in a Redux store?

Answer (score 6):

In my experience things like socket connections and, as in your case, webrtc things, are well-suited for living inside their own middlewares hand-written for your application. You can wire up all connection management here, fire actions to communicate with UI and listen for actions coming from here.

Another solution would be to look on [redux saga](http://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/), which seems to be quite a nice option for handling complex effects as sockets and webrtc.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how using `redux-saga` would help? I'm looking to solve a similar problem and posted an issue there: https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga/issues/635

Comment: @Tauren the main idea here is to set up socket/webRTC connection at saga's code and push updates through actions to be handled later with reducers and, finally components. As for your task from the issue, I don't have any experience with video streaming and webRTC, so couldn't say anything on the matter.

Comment: FYI, ```redux-observable``` would be a nice alternative to saga if you would prefer observable approach instead of generators. https://redux-observable.js.org/

Comment: @JacopKane I ended up using `redux-saga` but I'm now seriously considering using `redux-observable`. Now that I've worked on this for a while, I think leveraging RxJS and observables may simplify things.

Comment: @Tauren I experimented with both only for few days. Both have some learning curve, for saga it was generators. For observable it was Rx obviously. Rx is a bit scary at first but than starting to being more fun and you can think it's underscore for observables.