# managing webRTC state (streams) in a react/redux app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, webrtc, agora-web-sdk-ng

I'm developing a video chat app with react and using redux for state management. Currently using agora for webRTC. As webRTC related events happen (streams get added, removed, and a whole lot more), the state should be updated and sent to all the components that need/depend on it.

However, redux alone is not meant for this. As discussed in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34137783/where-to-store-webrtc-streams-when-building-react-app-with-redux), and by [Dan Abramov (the maker himself)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098125/how-to-divide-the-logic-between-redux-reducers-and-action-creators/34135166#34135166), redux is not meant for classes, therefore storing webRTC streams there is a bad idea.

I suppose that I should have my own webRTC state stored and managed manually (somewhere, idk where

Still, I'm having a hard time understanding how to store the webRTC streams myself:

1. I believe using context API will cause all my components to render every time a stream changes/is added/is removed/anything else related happens.
2. Managing the webRTC state on a react function component will quickly become a nightmare, as I'll have to do it at the top level, and pass it down almost everywhere.
3. redux-saga is mentioned as a potential savior, but I'm kind of new to this and it's unclear to me how this can help as it seems to mainly handle side-effects and async calls. I need a parallel store (AFAI Understand)

bottom line:

Can someone please give a good and detailed explanation or point me to a repo with code that does this well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good base example code in the redux-saga documentation that manages events from a websocket - which is not too different than events from a webRTC client.

https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Channels.html

Comment: How did you avoid saving stream clasdes in the store?