# Put business logic in one place with Redux

Tags: javascript, redux

I like Redux. It is simple and powerful.
But when I started using it in real word, one architectural question drives me mad.

How to locate my business logic in one place?

Because I have 2 possible places where to locate it:

- Action Creators (AC)
- Store Reducers (SR)

`[AC] -> [Action] -> [SR]`

Below is 3 examples.
Ex. 1 and 2 - locate business decisions in AC and SR in sync scenario.
Ex. 3 - business decision made in AC in async scenario.

In my project I've noticed how business decisions are getting scattered between AC and SR very quickly. So each time I want to debug something I should ask myself - ok, so where that decision I want to check is located, AC or SR?
From architectural point of view, I'd rather want to split BL by domains, not by AC/SR.

**My point**: while I understand advantages of pure reducers that make hot-reloading, time-travel, undo/redo features possible, I'm not sure I'm ready to trade logic maintainability for that.

Still, I have only one week with Redux.
What have I missed?

---

Example 1 (sync, decisions are in reducer):

```
// action-creators.js

export function increment() {
  return {
    type: 'INCREMENT'
  }
}

export function decrement() {
  return {
    type: 'DECREMENT'
  }
}

// counter-reducer.js

export default function counter(state = 0, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'INCREMENT':
    return state + 1  // (!) decision of how to '(in|de)crement' is here
  case 'DECREMENT':
    return state - 1
  default:
    return state
  }
}
```

---

Example 2 (sync, decisions are in action creators):

```
// action-creators.js

export function increment() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return {
      type: 'CHANGE_COUNTER',
      newValue: getState() + 1 // (!) decision of how to '(in|de)crement' is here
    }
  };
}

export function decrement() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return {
      type: 'CHANGE_COUNTER',
      newValue: getState() - 1
    }
  };
}

// counter-reducer.js

export default function counter(state = 0, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'CHANGE_COUNTER':
    return action.newValue
  default:
    return state
  }
}
```

---

Example 3 (async, decisions are in action creators):

```
// action-creators.js

export function login() {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    let isLoggedIn = await api.getLoginState();

    if (!isLoggedIn) {  // (!) decision of whether to make second api call or not
      let {user, pass} = getState();
      await api.login(user, pass)
    }

    dispatch({
      type: 'MOVE_TO_DASHBOARD'
    })
  };
}

// some-reducer.js

export default function someReducer(state = 0, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'MOVE_TO_DASHBOARD':
    return {
      ...state,
      screen: 'dashboard'
    }
  default:
    return state
  }
}
```

---

Comment: I don't think there's any one answer to this but I've grouped business logic by directories. Each directory would contain 1 action file (N of exports) and 1 reducer file (N of exports). It also helps think about how your actions will evolve over time. I found that actions needed more time to design because they can contain side effects now or in the future.

Comment: Here's what Dan has to say about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35357629/where-to-put-model-specific-business-logic-in-a-redux-app

Comment: @MattLo, yep, I've also grouped logic by domains, and separate folder for each domain (authorization, entities, etc.), with 2 files in each folder - AC and SR files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've pretty well covered the possibilities.  Unfortunately, there is no one-size-fits-all answer.  It's your app, you'll have to decide.

The Redux FAQ answer on [structuring business logic](https://redux.js.org/faq/code-structure#how-should-i-split-my-logic-between-reducers-and-action-creators-where-should-my-business-logic-go) has a good quote on the topic, and links to a few related discussions.

Comment: Ok. Official FAQ addresses my exact question. Answer as I see it: "Yes, you have 2 places to locate your BL. Now you should decide yourself how to organize your code - (fat AC/thin SR), or vice verse". 1 - I do not see option to do (thin AC/fat SR) scenario, since I forced to locate my async actions in AC already, I end up with (fat AC/thin SR). 2 - Ideally I would prefer some framework build on top of Redux, that will enforce me and my teammates to follow one concrete approach, and not leave it to developer discipline.

Comment: Yeah, there's actually been an additional bunch of comments on https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1171 discussing this issue.

You might be able to find something relevant in my Redux libraries list at https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links .  The "variations" page in particular has a lot of libraries that use Redux as a base, but go off in some specific direction from there.

Not sure you'll find anything that strictly enforces an absolute pattern, though.