# Why separate actions + reducers In Redux?

Tags: redux

I've seen the argument for separating actions and reducers because they have a many-to-many relationship.

I don't think that actually applies in Redux though. Because there's only 1 datastore, actions to reducers should be 1-to-many.

Typically reducers apply to a specific change for a specific datastore.

```
MY_ACTION = "MY_ACTION"
function reducer(state, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case MY_ACTION: // stuff with my action to create new state
        default: return state
    }
}
```

We can combine multiple reducers with `combineReducers` so why not define the handler for an action with the action itself.

For instance

```
class Action {
    constructor(type) {
        this.type = type
        this.handlers = []
    }
    add_handler(handler) {
        this.handlers += handler
    }
    get_reducer() {
        reducer = combineReducers(this.handlers)
        return (state, action) => {
            if(action.type == this.type) {
                return reducer(state, action)
            }
            return state
        }
    }
}
```

With the "ducks" pattern, we end up putting the main reducers in the same module as the action declaration.

Is there any reason to keep reducers + actions separate with redux?

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking or illustrating.

Answer (score 3):

The main reason for separating the action creators from the reducer function is that the reducer function must be a pure function. If you wanted to do something in an action creator, like an asynchronous API call for instance, then you could not put this in the reducer. There's a great explanation on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34098125/how-to-divide-the-logic-between-redux-reducers-and-action-creators).

Comment: I can add, that you don't want your reducers to access ajax calls, services/functions with sideeffects .. for same reason (they should be pure).

The action creators can access services, and create side effects all they want.. maybe your application structure makes it too spaghetti-like if you put actions creators and reducers in the same place.

Concretely, my Angular2 application is structured in modules, and I don't want my store-module to be able to access any services etc.

On the other hand, the action creators need to access all kinds of services, so they need access to more...

Comment: The question was about WHY it should be like that, which is not answered here.